# Postgres - RDS Replica of multiple databases into single database seperated by schemas (database name)

Tags: postgresql, metabase

I am hosting multiple Postgres databases on Amazon RDS Instance.

Now I want to connect it with Metabase to draw visualizations, but Metabase doesn't allow you to perform join between multiple databases.

I have tried by creating Foreign Data Wrappers, but that is very slow.

Is there any way to create read replicas of multiple databases into a single database separated by schemas (database name)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/logical-replication.html) for this.  It does seem to be [supported by RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Replication.Logical.html), but with slightly different mechanisms than the community PostgreSQL.

But when you use normal built-in logical replication, the schema name needs to be the same between the master and the replica, so each master would need to have the schemas "pre-organized" so they don't clash when combined.  Maybe RDS has invented some other solution to that.

> I have tried by creating Foreign Data Wrappers, but that is very slow.

Have you put some time into trying to speed it up?  It might be useful to play with use_remote_estimate, fetch_size, and (on the foreign end) cursor_tuple_fraction.  In addition to the normal [performance tuning suggestions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info).

> Is there any way to create read replicas of multiple databases into a single database separated by schemas (database name)

Schemas and database names are different things in PostgreSQL.  If you put them in separate databases, you would still need FDW to query across them.  Although having them on the same machine would reduce latency and so might fix performance problems.